# Spring-Security : Accessing secured resources using cookie returned at login

Tags: java, spring, cookies, spring-security, resttemplate

I am working on a Java desktop application and after some search I was able to authenticate the user using RestTemplate. Now the situation is I have the cookie String at the desktop side(code given below). Now what I would like to do is to do two important things, get which user logged in using that cookie and access(GET,POST,DELETE) secured resources which are marked with @Secured or @PreAuthorize annotation.

here is my authentication code :

```
   @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        submitButton.setOnAction(event -> {
           if(!(usernameField.getText().isEmpty() && passwordField.getText().isEmpty())){
               try {
                   RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
                   String jsessionid = rest.execute("http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check", HttpMethod.POST,
                           new RequestCallback() {
                               @Override
                               public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                                   request.getBody().write(("j_username=" + usernameField.getText() + "&j_password=" + passwordField.getText()).getBytes());
                               }
                           }, new ResponseExtractor<String>() {
                               @Override
                               public String extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                                   List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Cookie");

                                   // assuming only one cookie with jsessionid as the only value
                                   if (cookies == null) {
                                       cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
                                   }

                                   String cookie = cookies.get(cookies.size() - 1);
                                   System.out.println("Cookie is "+cookie);
                                   int start = cookie.indexOf('=');
                                   int end = cookie.indexOf(';');

                                   return cookie.substring(start + 1, end);
                               }
                           });

              //   rest.put("http://localhost:8080/rest/program.json;jsessionid=" + jsessionid, new DAO("REST Test").asJSON());

               } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                   System.out.println("AuthenticationException");
               }
           } else {
               System.out.println("Fields are empty");
           }
        });
    }
```

Output of program is :

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for "http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check"
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for "http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check" resulted in 302 (Found)
Cookie is JSESSIONID=903B2924CCC84421931D52A4F0AA3C7E; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

If I was on server-side, I would have simply called the below method to get the currently authenticated user :

```
 @Override
    public Person getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return personDAO.findPersonByUsername(authentication.getName());
        }
    }
```

How can I get the currently authenticate user on desktop based java app so I can just use below method and authenticate on desktop java app. :

```
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(person1, null, authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

This way, I can use @Secured annotations for the desktop java app as well. Thanks a lot.

*Update*

So on the server side I have created a method which gives me the logged in user. As suggested in an answer, I can use the same rest template, but I would like to store the cookie in users local db instead of passing the Resttemplates object around when user clicks here and there.

Server side method :

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/getloggedinuser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<RestPerson> getLoggedInRestUser() {
    Person person = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
    RestPerson restPerson = new RestPerson();
    restPerson.setFirstname(person.getFirstName());
    restPerson.setUsername(person.getUsername());
    restPerson.setPassword("PROTECTED");
    return new ResponseEntity<RestPerson>(restPerson, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now, next for now, I am trying to use the same RestTemplate to check if this method works with code below, but I would really like to know how I can do this with just a cookie :

```
 HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                                   requestHeaders.add("Cookie", cookie);
                                   HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
                                   ResponseEntity rssResponse = rest.exchange(
                                           "/rest/getloggedinuser",
                                           HttpMethod.GET,
                                           requestEntity,
                                           Person.class);
                                   String rssResponseBody = (String)rssResponse.getBody();
                                   System.out.println("Response body is ");
```

Is there a way to cast the Object in the ResponseBody to the Person object???

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get some user information which is stored on the server-side, you should create a new service, for example "getUserInformation" on your server, which will provide such information.
2. You should not extract cookies manually, just reuse the same RestTemplate, it stores cookies internally (specifically in the underlying HttpClient). That's how you can reach secure resources.

**UPDATE:**

You don't need to pass around the RestTemplate, just make it a singleton and use it everywhere.

And `rssResponse.getBody();` should return you a Person object, not String.

Comment: I have already created the method on server-side to get the Person object. That's what I was about to try. My idea was that I could somehow save the cookie on the local user machines DB so I dont need to keep passing the RestTemplate object when user clicks around.

Comment: Can you please check the updated post, I have added information at the bottom of it. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Can you tell me where I can create the RestTemplate as Singleton?